# What does $DISPLAY environment variable mean

Tags: xorg

What does $DISPLAY environment variable mean if the value is greater than 0 on my local machine?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947681/understanding-linux-display-variable) may interest you.

Comment: Thanks @KGIII But this is a simple desktop, why would it be > 0?

Comment: how to prevent desktop sharing -- if that's what it is?

Comment: why would a desktop have 2 xservers running?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $DISPLAY`? Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you running? Are there more than one screen/monitor? Did you install an SSH server?

Comment: well, there are 2 .X11-unix/Xn files. There is only 1 monitor, there shouldnt be an ssh server. v20.

Answer (score 2):

From `man X`:

```
From the user's perspective, every X server has a display name of the form:

  hostname:displaynumber.screennumber

This information is used by the application to determine how it should connect to the server and which screen it should use by default (on displays
with multiple monitors):

hostname
   The  hostname specifies the name of the machine to which the display is physically connected.  If the hostname is not given, the most effi‐
   cient way of communicating to a server on the same machine will be used.

displaynumber
   The phrase "display" is usually used to refer to a collection of monitors that share a  common  set  of  input  devices  (keyboard,  mouse,
   tablet,  etc.).  Most workstations tend to only have one display.  Larger, multi-user systems, however, frequently have several displays so
   that more than one person can be doing graphics work at once.  To avoid confusion, each display on a machine is assigned a  display  number
   (beginning at 0) when the X server for that display is started.  The display number must always be given in a display name.

...

ENVIRONMENT
 DISPLAY
   This is the only mandatory environment variable. It must point to an X server. See section "Display Names" above.
```

Comment: why would a simple desktop have multiple xservers running?

Comment: @uan I don't think it is that are multiple servers running, but that the server assigns the number 1 to the display.

Comment: there are 2 .X11-unix/Xn files

Comment: Where are those files?